Do “being not rich” and “not being rich” mean the same or different things? Is either ungrammatical or unheard of?
Which word should you negate with not here: the non-finite ‑ɪɴɢ verb in the first case, or its predicate adjective in the second case?

Being not rich, he couldn't help people.
Not being rich, he couldn't help people.

Between those two cases, which is grammatical in English from a formal, written, school-of-grammar point of view, and why? Please select exactly one answer from the following four possibilities, then explain why:

Only (1) is grammatical.
Onle (2) is grammatical.
Both (1) and (2) are grammatical.
Neither (1) nor (2) is grammatical.

If both are grammatical, do they always mean the same thing and do both occur with similar frequency?
Can the not at the very front shown in the second case ever be thought of as applying to the entire verb phrase, not merely to the first word alone, so like not(being rich) rather than like (not being) rich?
Apart from simple grammatical mechanics, are there any other matters that should be taken into account in choosing one or the other to produce a natural-sounding sentence that won’t sound weird to native speakers?

The first form was much more common a couple of centuries ago, but even in its heyday, my example being not able to help was never anywhere near as common as not being able to help.

Thanks for your comment.
You said "Being not able to help, he couldn't help others" is awkward. right?

I didn't say that, no. But your exact example doesn't make sense to me - did you mean Being not able to help himself, he couldn't help others. If you follow that link you'll see that an awful lot of the matches are reflexive like that. It's "marked" (not the default sequence), so as a non-native speaker you should probably avoid it yourself. But competent native Anglophones might sometimes use the marked form quite deliberately, perhaps for some context-specific effect.

...also note that the specific context of not being / being not able to help oneself often has the very specific sense of being unable to control oneself (rather than being unable to improve one's situation). I think it's the very possibility of that specificity that sometimes encourages speakers / writers to choose the marked form - whichever of the two senses is intended should be contextually obvious, so the speaker uses the marked form to encourage the audience / reader to pay attention and make sure to pick the right sense.

The second one is the plain, matter-of-fact  formulation. The first one is also correct; the adverb is then modifying the adjective.

It can occur so as to make a correlation clearer, more pungent or so as to preserve the parallelism in a construction.

(How Not to Get Rich: Or Why Being Bad Off Isn't So Bad - Robert Sullivan · 2008) How often do we who are successfully not rich act as if we were unsuccessful at being not rich?

(Research Methods: Concepts, Methodologies, Tools, and ... - Management Association, Information Resources · 2015) There is no specific income level at which an individual goes from being rich to being not rich.

(Informal Logic: A Handbook for Critical Argument - Douglas N. Walton · 1989) There is no exact cutoff point at which a person may definitely said to pass from being not rich to rich.


It can also occur as a synonym of "not being rich" with no particular stylistic function in the sentence; apparently, this form is used much less often.

(Probationary Officers Exam - )  Being not rich by any means, he never turned away anyone who needed help.

(Common Sense vs. the World - Ronald J. Plachno · 2022) Yay! See? Being not rich has some advantages.



The NGram graph is worthless in this case.

@Robusto Is it not a proof that one form is more often used than the other? That's all it's meant to show.

I think your chart (usefully) shows that being not X has always been uncommon compared to not being X, but it doesn't clearly show what's obvious from the first chart in my comment under the question - that although being not X was never the default sequence, it's comparatively much rarer today than it was 200 years ago.

@LPH It doesn't show context, without which no judgment can be made. See Should we allow NGrams to be presented as statistical evidence without qualification?

@Robusto What other context can you discern than "not as negation of verb" in one case and "not as adverb modifying the adjective" in the other? Of course there might be complements such as in "not rich enough to…" and "not rich as …", but these are nothing than variants on the same root context. Can you give an example, so that I might see more clearly what you have in mind?

It doesn't have any context. Just this sentence.
